# How can an existential type be defined in terms of universal type?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, polymorphisms, types-and-programming-languages

In *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce,  how does the following achieve the definition of an existential type  in terms of universal type, by polymorphic version of Church encoding of pairs?

> **24.3 Encoding Existentials**
>
> **The encoding of pairs as a polymorphic type in §23.4** suggests a
>   similar **encoding for existential types in terms of universal types**,
>   using the intuition that an element of an existential type is a pair
>   of a type and a value:
>
> ```
> {∃X,T} := ∀Y. (∀X. T→Y) → Y.
> ```
>
> That is, an existential package is thought of as a data value that,
>   given a result type and a continuation, calls the continuation to
>   yield a ﬁnal result. The continuation takes two arguments—a type X and
>   a value of type T—and uses them in computing the ﬁnal result.

To complete the quote, the polymorphic version of Church encoding of pairs of numbers is given in Exercise 23.4.8 (p349 p546):

```
pairNat = λn1:CNat. λn2:CNat.
λX. λf:CNat→CNat→X. f n1 n2;
fstNat = λp:PairNat. p [CNat] (λn1:CNat. λn2:CNat. n1);
sndNat = λp:PairNat. p [CNat] (λn1:CNat. λn2:CNat. n2);
```

which is further generalized to pairs of elements of any types, on p352

> we use the abbreviation Pair X Y (generalizing the PairNat type from
>   Exercise 23.4.8) for the Church encoding of pairs with ﬁrst component
>   of type X and second component of type Y:
>
> ```
> Pair X Y = ∀R. (X→Y→R) → R;
> ```
>
> The operations on pairs are simple generalizations of the operations
>   on the type PairNat above:
>
> ```
> > pair : ∀X. ∀Y. X → Y → Pair X Y
> fst : ∀X. ∀Y. Pair X Y → X
> snd : ∀X. ∀Y. Pair X Y → Y
> ```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the question here? Are you saying that `Pair X Y` is an encoding of a variant type `X + Y`? Because it isn't.

Comment: typo: variant -> existential

Comment: Well, I answered both :-)

Answer (score 5):

As a general recipe, to figure out how to encode a type `A`, write down

```
∀Z . (A → Z) → Z
```

and massage it to something that does not involve `A`, using basic isomorphisms, such as currying and uncurrying. For example, if we plug in `A := X + Y` we get:

```
∀ Z . (X + Y → Z) → Z           ≅
∀ Z . (X → Z) × (Y → Z) → Z     ≅
∀ Z . (X → Z) → (Y → Z) → Z
```

You can also read the above lines as a sequence of logical equivalences. So this gives us the encoding of `X + Y` in terms of the universal quantifier.

I do not understand why in your question you speak about existential types, but since you do, it is worth explaining the encoding of `∃ X . B(X)` in terms of `∀` this way:

```
∀ Z . ((∃ X . B(X)) → Z) → Z    ≅
∀ Z . (∀ X . (B(X) → Z)) → Z
```

Again, you can read the equivalence either as a type isomorphism or a logical equivalence in logic, using the fact that $(\exists x . \phi(x)) \Rightarrow \psi$ is equivalent to $\forall x . (\phi(x) \Rightarrow \psi))$.

Answer (score 0):

At chapter 5 of TaPL, we saw that
in untyped lambda calculus.

```
pair f s = \b . b f s 
fst p = p tru 
snd p = p fls 

where 
tru = \t. \f. t
fls = \t. \f. f
```

This definition of pair is to be typed now. 
Here, `b` takes two arguments `f:F` and `s:S` and we assume the resulting type is `R`. 
so,

```
b : F -> S -> R 
b f s : R
```

now we apply quantification to this `R` which can be any type.
so we will get the typed version ;

```
pair f s : ∀R. (F -> S -> R) -> R
```

which should result in

```
Pair F S = ∀R. (F -> S -> R) -> R
```

Then assigning  `F = ∃X`, `S = T` , and `R = Y`, we get;

```
Pair (∃X) T = ∀R. ((∃X) -> T -> Y ) -> Y
```

, and uncurrying can reach the following result;

```
Pair (∃X) T = ∀R. (((∃X) x T )-> Y ) -> Y
```

which is the same with

```
Pair (∃X) T = ∀R. ((∃X. T )-> Y ) -> Y
```

and it is equivalent to

```
Pair (∃X) T = ∀R. (∀X. T -> Y ) -> Y
```